# Would we benefit from separate [unity-2d] and [unity-3d] tags?

Tags: support, tags

As part of my editing recently, I've been [removing a lot of tags from titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/152515). One of the consistent patterns I see coming up regularly are for people to say they're using "[Unity 2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22unity+2d%22+is%3Aquestion)" or "[Unity 3D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22unity+3d%22+is%3Aquestion)".

Are these substantially important enough that we should have [unity-2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-2d) and [unity-3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-3d) tags for people to specify? People seem to feel the need to specify as such in their titles, so I see there might be a case for this, but I don't know well enough about Unity to be able to be sure myself.

I'll note I see that [unity3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) is already a synonym of [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity), so I'm braced that the answer might be "no".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need such distinction in [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) tags.

We have the tags [2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d) and [3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d) which can be used to narrow the domain of the questions. That's not exactly the way the tags are designed to be used, but that's how they're used now.

Also, adding a distinction between unity2d and unity3d, I feel we'd get questions bloated with redundant and inappropriate tags:

- `unity`
- `unity` `unity2d`
- `unity2d` `unity3d`
- and all of the other combinations...

`unity3d` was probably put in place because the 'official' name of the engine was 'unity3d'.

Note that in the past, we've been marking some unity related tags as blacklisted, or as synonym, such as [inspector](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspector), as they did not add much value to the site.

Comment: I believe Unity was earlier more commonly known as *unity3d*, and was initially only *for* 3D game development. AFAIK, 2D was further integrated, when it became apparent that the engine *was* being used for 2D game development

Comment: @Gnemlock I agree that was the original name for it. "unity3d.com" is still their official web domain, their official twitter handle is [@unity3d](https://twitter.com/unity3d), and old articles like [this one from 2012](https://venturebeat.com/2012/11/02/game-developers-start-your-unity-3d-engines-interview/) call it "Unity 3D".

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: @doppelgreener While true, it is now officially called "Unity." The URL and twitter handlers were maintained and old docs and articles weren't updated (who would bother?), although the company also owns unity.com (and uses it as a spotlight website to highlight things developers have done) and do (seem to) control the [@unity twitter handle](https://twitter.com/unity) (it is unused and the only info on the profile is a link to unity3d.com).

Answer (score 2):

I brought up some discussion on the various meta tags of Unity, and in turn, we merged a few into the [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag.

You would not be versed in using Unity for 3D, and not be versed in using Unity for 2D. Tags are used to identify areas of expertise, and as such, I feel it is appropriate to use [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) under either circumstance. At the end of the day, there is very little (if any) difference between using Unity for a 2D game or a 3D game. As such, -2D and -3D are only meta tags, being used to describe the specific context.

Ultimately, we would *not* benefit from differentiating between *unity-2d* and *unity-3d*.